# Community Promotion Ads - 2017

Tags: discussion, community-ads

It is a bit late into this new year, being that we're already in the second month, but we are now cycling the Community Promotion Ads for 2017!

#### What are Community Promotion Ads?

Community Promotion Ads are community-vetted advertisements that will show up on the main site, in the right sidebar. The purpose of this question is the vetting process. Images of the advertisements are provided, and community voting will enable the advertisements to be shown.

#### Why do we have Community Promotion Ads?

This is a method for the community to control what gets promoted to visitors on the site. For example, you might promote the following things:

- the site's amazing blog
- useful tools or resources for understanding worlds
- blogs or articles of existing interesting worlds
- cool events or conferences
- anything else your community would genuinely be interested in

The goal is for future visitors to find out about *the stuff your community deems important*. This also serves as a way to promote information and resources that are *relevant to your own community's interests*, both for those already in the community and those yet to join.

#### Why do we reset the ads every year?

Some services will maintain usefulness over the years, while other things will wane to allow for new faces to show up. Resetting the ads every year helps accommodate this, and allows old ads that have served their purpose to be cycled out for fresher ads for newer things. This helps keep the material in the ads relevant to not just the subject matter of the community, but to the current status of the community. We reset the ads once a year, every December.

The community promotion ads have no restrictions against reposting an ad from a previous cycle. If a particular service or ad is very valuable to the community and will continue to be so, it is a good idea to repost it. It may be helpful to give it a new face in the process, so as to prevent the imagery of the ad from getting stale after a year of exposure.

#### How does it work?

The answers you post to this question *must* conform to the following rules, or they will be ignored.

1. All answers should be in the exact form of:

   ```
   [![Tagline to show on mouseover][1]][2]

      [1]: http://image-url
      [2]: http://clickthrough-url
   ```

   Please **do not add anything else to the body of the post**. If you want to discuss something, do it in the comments.
2. The question must always be tagged with the magic [community-ads](/questions/tagged/community-ads) tag. In addition to enabling the functionality of the advertisements, this tag also pre-fills the answer form with the above required form.

#### Image requirements

- The image that you create must be 300 x 250 pixels, or double that if high DPI.
- Must be hosted through our standard image uploader (imgur)
- Must be GIF or PNG
- No animated GIFs
- Absolute limit on file size of 150 KB
- If the background of the image is white or partially white, there must be a 1px border (2px if high DPI) surrounding it.

#### Score Threshold

There is a **minimum score threshold** an answer must meet (currently **6**) before it will be shown on the main site.

You can check out the ads that have met the threshold with basic click stats [here](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/ads/display/4377).

Comment: Traditionally, we would post a sample ad with the site's twitter, but unfortunately <site> does not have a twitter account. [Here's an example of one, though](http://meta.aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/3186/community-promotion-ads-2017/3187#3187).

Comment: Umm... You do mean Worldbuilding instead of <site> right?

Comment: @Zizouz212 presumably.  This question just got posted on dozens of sites, and this comment on the subset of them that don't have Twitter feeds, so there's almost certainly a script driving it.

Comment: @MonicaCellio Yeah, probably. I couldn't possibly imagine posting it manually on every site :/

Comment: @Zizouz212 Just imagine all the notifications poor Grace Note gets from answers on these CPA posts all across the network!

Answer (score 27):

[image: Visit Writers Stack Exchange]

Comment: Ad made by Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2  ([source](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/168?m=34510574#34510574))

Answer (score 26):

[image: Visit Universe Factory, our community-run blog!]

Answer (score 23):

[image: Q&A about works of sci-fi and fantasy!]

Comment: Credit to [CreationEdge](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/users/31178/creationedge) for designing this ad.

Comment: That's very pretty!

Comment: Full disclaimer, the design & graphics are pulled straight from our theme and I used the same font faces as our theme. I've always enjoyed looking at them and felt they made a lot of sense for a Worldbuilding ad.

Comment: I wish the text on this ad said "stack exchange". Without that, it looks to me like just an ad to go read sci-fi/fantasy books.

Answer (score 19):

[image: Discuss the real world. Start Urban Planning SE!]

Comment: Continuing from last year... I'll get started on a proper image

Comment: New image is much better.

Comment: The text looks a bit weak when displayed at 300x250, and the font is a little dull. Maybe an [engineering/lettering font](https://www.google.com.au/search?tbm=isch&q=engineering+lettering+font)?

Answer (score 15):

[image: Share your work on the blog -- we'll help!]

Answer (score 14):

[image: Get inspired by reading!]

Comment: Ad designed by [@BESW](http://meta.literature.stackexchange.com/a/423/17).

Answer (score 10):

[image: RPG.SE]

Answer (score 6):

[image: Stack Exchange Q&A site proposal: Constructed languages]

Comment: Is this non-standard formatting equivalent to the one given in the question?

Comment: @HDE226868 - what?

Comment: Looks like this ad is [showing up as blank](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/ads/display/4377). Not sure why, but presumably that's the formatting issue which HDE mentioned.

Answer (score 4):

[image: The guild for professional world builders.]

Answer (score 4):

[image: Writer Beware: A blog about publishers taking advantage of unsuspecting authors]

Comment: This is an industry service endorsed by the Science Fiction and Fantasy Writers of America. Writer Beware keeps track of publishers both major and minor and tries to keep the writing community aware of any scams -- and there are many people who like to steal IP from authors. Protect yourself!

Comment: This looks like a useful site (of which I was not previously aware).  But could you tone down "bastards" here?  Consider "scoundrels" instead.

Comment: @MonicaCellio Done. But, honestly, I never would have guessed anyone would have had a problem with the term "bastard" in this context. In my world, it is innocuous.

Comment: @SRM It's a pretty safe one for most contexts, but it's still on the naughty word list. For a large network like SE, it's better to be safe than sorry. Anyway, you have my upvote it looks great now.

Answer (score 4):

[image: Cartography Stack Exchange proposal]

Answer (score 2):

[image: The Submission Grinder helps authors find publishers.]