# Inactive Sandbox 2018

Tags: discussion, questions, sandbox

**This sandbox is inactive.  Please visit the next [Sandbox for Proposed Questions](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7183/sandbox-for-proposed-questions)**

---

[In order to make the Sandbox easier to use](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3813/6507), a new Sandbox question will be posted when the old one becomes too full. **This Sandbox is currently active**. You can check [here](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/635/sandbox-for-proposed-questions-2014-2017) for the full list of past and present Question Sandboxes.

## What is the Sandbox?

This ["Sandbox"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sandbox_(software_development)) is a place where Worldbuilding.SE users can get feedback on prospective questions they wish to [post](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions). This is useful because writing a clear and fully specified question on the first try can be difficult. There is a much better chance of your question being well received if you post it in the Sandbox first.

**To post a question to the Sandbox:**
Post an answer to this post with the content of your proposed question. You can create as many answers as you have proposed questions, but it is recommended that you only work on one question at a time. The content of the post should be as close as possible to the format you would use when asking on the main site. If you would like, you may add a section at the bottom explaining what parts of the proposed question you are most worried about (See the [Sandbox FAQ](http://meta.worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/640/2685) for more information on suggested syntax).

**Once you have posted your proposed question,** users will be able to comment on it with feedback. You can then respond to their feedback with comments of your own, or make edits to your post to attempt to address their feedback (after editing, be sure to comment to notify the user that you have taken their advice). The feedback/edit cycle can go on for as long as needed until either you are confident that your question is ready to be asked on the main site, or you've decided the question just won't work.

**When you think your question is ready for the public**, go ahead and [post it to the main site](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). To help keep this sandbox clean, you should edit your post here so that it contains the title and URL of the posted question, and nothing else. Regardless of whether or not you decided to post to the main site, **once you are done with your Sandbox post, you should delete it**. This will not completely delete the post, but it will get it out of the way so that new proposed questions can be more easily located.

**Keep the Sandbox clean.** In order to [keep the Sandbox clean](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2244/sandbox-cleanup) users are encouraged to [look out for questions that have not seen any activity in some time](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4912/28789). If you come across a question draft that has not seen any activity from the author in the form of edits to the draft and comments as responses to other peoples comments you should leave a comment. In the comment you should ask if the user is still working on the question draft and remind him that his post might be deleted in the future if there is no further activity. If you see a question draft that has not seen any activity for at least 30 days and that has had a comment asking if the author is still working on the question draft for at least a week you should flag the post for moderator attention and ask for deletion. This helps to keep the Sandbox clean in cases where the author has abandoned his question draft.

**Delete your comments when they no longer apply.** It's normal that the OP will incorporate the feedback they get into their posts. Please make it easy for others to see which comments are still relevant to the discussion by removing your obsolete ones. In addition you can ask a mod to [purge comments under graduated posts or move them to chat under abandoned posts](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6231/28789) to make it easier for users that can see deleted posts to use the Sandbox.

**Use votes sparingly.** [Up- and Downvotes in the Sandbox](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6362/28789) should be used sparingly as the drafts here are supposed to be questions that would not fit the guidelines of the Main site in their current form. Only upvote if you think a draft is ready for the Main site and only downvote if you think that a question is just not a good fit, no matter how much the OP works on the draft. In any case, please write a comment to explain your voting. We don't want to unnecessarily discourage the OP, but we also don't want them to waste their time.

**Please avoid answering questions here.** I know it's tempting, but answering the question in a comment will clog the comments and make it harder to see good guidance. If you have an answer for the proposed question, simply wait for it to be posted to the main site, and answer it there.

**See the [Sandbox FAQ](http://meta.worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/639/2685) for more information on how to use the Sandbox.**

**Please make sure you wait at least a day after posting into the Sandbox to give a range of people time to see the question and respond.**

### The Sandbox works best if you sort posts by "active" (click [here](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6168?answertab=active) to do so).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In accordance with http://meta.worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/1728/sandbox-overflow, answers containing graduated questions will be deleted. This is designed to be a repository for all those questions that have graduated. It is a community wiki answer, so add in your question here, at the end of the list once it is posted on the main site!

1. [Steam Powered Hammer](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/112754)
2. [Can I have droplets of fluids that aren't... well... droplets?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/113637)
3. [Resources For Building A Fictional Language [DELETED]](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/113971)
4. [How to modify bee physiology to be able to produce firehoney given nectar that is (magically) flammable?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/113992)
5. [How can I realistically make a worldwide government that works with my fictional world with different magical races?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/114056)
6. [How To Make an Earth with 27 Suns Work, Attempt Two: Orbital Stability](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/114107)
7. [Best material for windsilk](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/114147)
8. [How can humans retain the benefits of sleep through meditation?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/114347)
9. [Mosquito Armageddon](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/114832)
10. [Ringed planet: Reality check on ring-shadow visuals](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/114877)
11. [Sailing without wind, but with strong currents](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/115190)
12. [Traffic using personal airplanes?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/115231)
13. [Metal-Feathered Macaw Viability Part 1: How Can It Fly?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/115491)
14. [How can a single clergy rule over a religion that has different interpretations of its deity?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/115401)
15. [Sugar-bomb tree mechanics](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/115770)
16. [Slowing or Averting Global Warming With the Help of Elemental Powers: Part 1 (Fire)](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/115905)
17. [How could an acid-cow make a barrier against acidic milk by synthesizing PTFE, and what would it line?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/116270)
18. [Metal-Feathered Macaw Viability Part 2: Best Wing Shape?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/116518)
19. [Anatomically Correct Siren?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/116508)
20. [How would a humanoid need to change to sleep upside-down?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/116848)
21. [The flying state, estimating an "ideal" size](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/116909)
22. [How can I use magic to make childbirth easier?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/116871)
23. [Weaponry made from extreme light-weight steel: swords and daggers](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/117184)
24. [Designing venom glands for an elephant: misting](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/117425)
25. [Can using zombies for labor be more cost effective for an employer than a living worker?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/117575)
26. [How dangerous is someone who can make volumes of air act like immovable solids, measured by how expensive an army they could defeat?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/117687)
27. [How long should an elven generation be?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/118260)
28. [Music Dragonfly via Perforations in Wings](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/118644)
29. [What required secondary powers does my speedster need in order to be able to accelerate at 2,250 ft/s^2 without harmful effects?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/118648)
30. [Restricting antimatter - practical rather than legal measures](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/118966)
31. [Radiation Levels and Effects on Planet with 27 Suns](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/119148)
32. [Regrowing body parts: What are the costs?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/119337)
33. [How can chi be used to preserve a man's fertility? [DELETED]](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/119452)
34. [Kidnapping Fire-Slugs](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/119666)
35. [Natural barriers around medieval towns](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/119723)
36. [Quick solutions to a modern warning placed on the surface of a planet for future generations](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/119834)
37. [I travel back in time: how could I know when I landed?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/120207)
38. [To Conquer the Earth by Appearing Ship](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/120494)
39. [Worse than zombies, part 1](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/120571)
40. [How to build a Blood Gun?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/120592)
41. [Aftermath of a Midas-weapon war - what to do with all that gold?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/120453)
42. [(Porcu)pine tree needle firing system?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/120791)
43. [How could a medieval army defeat Sauron's army?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/120752)
44. [How to combat magic as science?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/120493)
45. [How high could a Lego tower be?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/120988)
46. [Should certain tags automatically require answers to use SI Units rather than other, more traditional, systems of measurement?](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6539)
47. [Extinction Equilibrium: 50%](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/121337)
48. [Fastest way for an invincible young immortal to make $1 million USD?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/121353)
49. https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/121447
50. [How many dead bodies are required to stain a river red?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/121571)
51. https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/121573
52. [How to design an advanced deadman's switch for the "vitality impaired"?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/121616)
53. [Ringstadt: How sensible is my topography?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/121834)
54. [Humans as repair drones](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/121954)
55. [Are competitive sports an effective way to change my Spartiates' life perspective?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/122266)
56. [What is a usable formula for determining the necessary strength of a planet’s magnetic field for it to be habitable?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/122300)
57. [Making the 'Master Swordsman' fantasy realistic?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/122428)
58. [Would planets be cubic in my "cuboverse"?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/122564)
59. [For how long can I hide the discovery of a new continent?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/122825)
60. [Ringstadt: Getting sulphur into my water](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/122862)
61. [Ringstadt: Can my mountains be what I need them to?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/122863)
62. [Taxing the superhero industry](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/122877)
63. [Could deliberately induced Kessler Syndrome stop ICBMs?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/123670)
64. [In modern day combat, what would warrant singing during battle?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/123060)
65. [Long-term effects of leaving everything you know - the aging issue](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/123990)
66. [What event would cause a huge, dominant nation to adopt the language of a smaller, inferior one?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/124021)
67. [What Would a Reptile with Facial Muscles look like?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/122524)
68. [From a software testing perspective, what quality-analysis tests would justify using a single world-war simulation?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/123633)
69. [What would be the pros and cons of a merged military and police?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/124100)
70. [Would interplanetary transmissions in the Wolf 359 star system be detectable by Earth?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/124607)
71. [Alien Senses: Active electrolocation](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/124815)
72. [Beings in Amnesia occuring after sleep, how to help them?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/125825)
73. [Feasibility of a Crystal Ecosystem](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/126184)
74. [What mandates travel in an interstellar society?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/126346)
75. [How would a world power create an artificial winter?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/126437)
76. [The Underdown, part 1: Size issues](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/127053)
77. [How can I test to find the continent's "best" young mages?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/127685)
78. [How many years could notebook computers and phones be stored in a closed bunker/vault and still operational when found?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/128387)
79. [Safely exiting zero-tau capsule](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/128227)
80. [Why isn't my superhuman always hungry?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/128863)
81. [How can I prevent a human sacrifice from dying before a ritual is complete?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/130384)
82. [How to accurately detect children with super strength?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/131028)
83. [How could I market beauty products to a species with a mating season?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/131499)
84. [How long would a flat Earth last?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/132294)
85. [Why would a religious person extract the hemoglobin of those who failed to survive his spiritual healing ritual?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/131594)
86. [How can I avoid accidentally killing my mages during a ritual?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/134107)
87. [How would a matriarchy rationalize infanticide?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/134341/)
88. [What (modern) weapons could be used to destroy skeletal enemies as completely as possible?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/136083/)
89. [The Dark is strong in the light! Why?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/136328/)
90. [What can a bunch of American kids teach ancient Egyptians?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/132335/what-can-a-bunch-of-american-kids-teach-ancient-egyptians)
91. [Economically feasible hard sci-fi non-microscopic wormhole](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/137170/7974)
92. [How tall can you built a mountain chain of bricks?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/137383/35308)
93. [Is a coral-based planet possible?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/137472/6620)
94. [How quickly and accurately should news travel in a rural medieval setting?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/13) (this link appears to be incorrect)
95. [How can the church stop the Mass media from spreading throughout medieval Europe?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/134705/)

Answer (score 1):

## World-splitting Wall: Impact on Weather

Tags: [science-based](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/science-based)[weather](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/weather)[climate](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/climate)[science-fiction](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/science-fiction)

---

#### The question

I asked recently in [this question](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/130027/most-cost-effective-way-to-fence-in-an-alien-wildlife-preserve/130123#130123) how paranoid aliens afraid of going the way described in "War of the Worlds" would sequester native flora and fauna in a preserve.

One of the coolest answers I saw was for the establishment of a wall, around my nature preserve, to preserve most native wildlife in its natural form. **What climate anomalies could occur on the edges of the dome?**

Notes:

- The moon itself is slightly larger than Mars, and orbits a Neptune-sized planet. It takes about 50 days to complete a roughly circular orbit.
- The moon's planet orbits at 0.63 AU, making for a 230-day orbital period
- The wall splits the moon directly in half, and is 10-15 miles tall
- The wall is covered/painted with a dirt-like material, and has psychological deterrents to any would-be wall-crossers.

---

#### Sandbox Questions

What issues would you have with this question?

Comment: Hi JavaScriptCoder, good edit! It's much clearer and more answerable. The biggest things I think we'll need to know are 1) whether the moon has an Earth-like environment or whether we're deriving climate effects from basic physics and 2) how large the moon is

Comment: Some comments as far as clarity goes: you only mention a "moon" in the notes on the question - I'd introduce that information earlier and provide some additional info about the world. Also, you say in one place that the wall goes all the way up to space, and in another that it's 10 miles tall. Finally, you've still got some references to a "dome" in there - maybe take those out or replace "dome" with "wall"?

Comment: Also, random thing I thought of while ruminating on this - does the wall split the world north/south or east/west or some other way? That'll change the answers a lot, with an equatorial wall having the least impact and a meridianal (meridinal?) wall having a much larger one.

Comment: Op are you still working on this?

Comment: Yeah, just waiting on more commentary

Comment: Cool, I'll read it and see.

Comment: I see that the moon's orbit round the planet takes roughly 50 days, how long does an eclipse last (ie. how long is the whole moon in the planet's umbra), does the moon have a day night cycle - ie what's it's rotational period? What's the nighttime brightness of the planet (say relative to Earth's moon, I don't need to know sky subtended, albedo etc.). when the planet is as Earth's full-moon? What dome? What direction does the wall run with reference to the axis of rotaton? Is that 10-15 miles above crust or above sea level or above land? Is there sea? Are there ice caps? Again, what dome?

Comment: @JavaScriptCoder As I see it, the bigest issue here is that you don't respond to people's comments. Dubukay's comment about the direction of the wall on the 16th January - nearly 4 weeks ago, and the weird reference to "Dome" that's been there and asked about for over a month without response. What's up, how can we help?

Comment: @FaySuggers sorry, I've been really busy between school, coding, chemistry, and other activities. I've just gotten back from Scouting, and am about to be AFK working on something else. The issue is that I have very little time... if you noticed my last question was from a month ago. I will try to reply within a week, but anything beyond that I cannot guarantee, as I usually have barely enough time for these comments.

Comment: @JavaScriptCoder I understand, if the question disappears into the system, I'm sure that you'll be able to ask it again anyhow. Best of luck.

Comment: @JBH I’ll delete ASAP, no longer worked on

Answer (score 0):

Can I put my potato into orbit?

————

The agricultural industry on Luna has been undergoing a boom of late, so much so that First Minister Boris Sonsson has decided a potato must be launched into lunar orbit to commemorate the hard work of the Farmers of the Moon. A popular vote (taken via completely tamperproof voting booths, of course) confirmed that this plan is what the Lunar public wants, regardless of expense.

Everyone in the lunar civil service knows this is ludicrous, and to make matters worse a series of long and complicated treaties with Earth and Mars mean that launching the potato with any form of onboard engine or guidance will be a process that could take decades or risk starting an interplanetary trade war.

As such the Technical Minister, Theresa Maybe, has come up with a plan.

First: A series of laser base stations with remarkable telescope arrays and accurate laser actuation will be built along the equator.

Second: A suitably large (and well pricked) potato will be loaded into a large pneumatic cannon and fired skywards.

Third: The base stations will track the potato and, at appropriate points, blast it with lasers. This should cause steam (and possibly roast potato chunks) to vent from the holes created by pricking the potato. By doing this the hope is that sufficient delta-v can be generated to put the potato into orbit.

If successful this will be used to launch all manner of vegetables, root or otherwise, as a show of strength and unity to ensure Luna gets good trade deals from the other spacefaring nations. The government don’t seem to have considered how to avoid intersecting orbits, but avoiding being peppered with de-orbiting mashed potato is a problem for future generations (like those lazy bimillennials, they need a good crisis).

Now, Theresa knows that this plan is pretty much unworkable, but the lunar government is scrabbling for ways to shore up the appearance that they know what they’re doing, so the question is this:

**Could this plan, or some variation on it, be used to put an unpowered potato into orbit?**

If not, why not, and can the Lunar government make it seem to their <s>gullible</s> loyal citizens that the plan is workable?

Answers will be ranked based on the number of factors considered and the potential for A: getting the potato to orbit or B: resolving the issues with getting the potato to orbit.

And as always remember: Porbit means Porbit.

*A quick note:* Vegetable themed humour aside, the core of this question is whether any organic, unpowered projectile can be launched into a stable (even on a short timescale) lunar orbit, but the world I’m building is almost unbearably satirical in nature.
———

I think this question is probably OK to go, but I’d like a second opinion as the tone is quite satirical in nature.

Comment: The only with this question is that the answer might just be a basic yes you can do it. It feels very scenario specific and I don't know if we close questions based on that (maybe too story based?). You could make it more generic using a general unpowered object rather than a potato. But I don't see any big issues.

Comment: @Shadowzee: Time to alter it to a generic vegetable moon-orbit launch system!

Comment: One-specific-question/one-best-answer.  I count two: (a) is X feasible? and (b) how do I convince X of Y?.  The question could use better organization (clearly separate background from the TL;DR actual question for ease-of-reading).  Otherwise, pick one question, (a) or (b), and you're ready to go.

Comment: Hello Joe.  As luck would have it, we're in need of closing this sandbox and [opening a new one](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7183). This is occasionally necessary as the web pages get too big. May I recommend that you wrap this up or, if you believe it needs more attention, re-post on the new site? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

## how can scientists prevent their advances in technology from making it into the mainstream society?

Reed Richards is a brilliant scientist who regularly tangoes with external threats to the planet Earth, where a race referred to as "humaniti" reside. He, along with a team of scientists, operate out of a metropolis city called New York. They regularly develop to advanced technology that is beyond anything this species has seen, and has access to offworld tech due to their repeated trips to outer space. Flying cars, teleport devices, etc, are just some of the kinds of tech they create and have access to. Because they sometimes defend earth from aliens, they get billions of dollars in tax breaks from the city. However, this has begun to provoke the ire of many New Yorkers.

A congresswoman named Alexandria Oscoria Cortez has recently come to prominence in the media, and has used her platform to attack Richards and his team. She argues that for decades, this group has kept their discoveries and advances to themselves. These developments have yet to make their way into mainstream society where they can benefit the common people. Instead, these well-paid elitists selfishly hoard them, neglecting to improve their city or humanity in the long term while still taking large tax breaks from the government. This shameful behavior is indicative of the wealthy 1% who have more power and control than the other 99% of society.

She has begun to make waves among other new yorkers, and has garnered a large amount of support, which has raised trouble for the superhero community. She is currently running for president of the U.S., and has proposed legislation called "The Green New Deal". This proposal will, among other things, end dependence on fossil fuel emissions, fix infrastructure in the country, and provide new jobs. This would be accomplished by forcing Richards to share his discoveries, and use the government to take control and regulate this company.

A wealthy billionaire by the name of Tony Stark has come to the defense of the scientists, and has  joined forces to take on AOC and her followers. I need to maintain the status quo of only the superhero community having access to these advances with tech. How can this group continue to legally keep their technology to themselves without sharing them?

Comment: *"They get billions of dollars in tax breaks from the city":* this is not how tax breaks work. Tax breaks are a reduction in taxes to be paid; they just reduce the amount paid **by** the scientists **to** the city. So the question is who *pays* those scientists. If they are paid by the city of New York, then their discoveries belong to the city, unless some special agreement is in place. The presidential candidate may or may not have a strong position for arguing that the scientists committed fraud by withholding their results from their employer.

Comment: What rule of your world is this about?  If you are only asking, "what laws can be passed..." the question will be on-topic, but likely too broad.  If you're opening it up to "what legal actions can be taken..." then this is too story-based.  Does all that narrative boil down to: I have scientists in 2019 New York who want to keep their inventions out of the hands of the public, how do they do that?  Or are you asking how to counter legislation in the U.S.?

Comment: And...  Is it still being worked on? Should it be promoted? Or should it be deleted?

Comment: Hello Incognito.  As luck would have it, we're in need of closing this sandbox and [opening a new one](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7183). This is occasionally necessary as the web pages get too big. May I recommend that you either wrap this post up or delete this post per the above instructions and re-post on the new site? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

## How can you link a plague or virus to a specific genetic signature?

A domestic terrorist organization has come to light due to recent terror attacks that they claim responsibility for. This group has developed a biological weaponized plague that attacks the nervous system of an individual. If released,  and has the potential to kill millions. The terrorists blame a particular minority group for what it sees as the nation's social and economic woes, and seeks to commit genocide by spreading this plague in the name of national defense. The intent is to only make this minority group susceptible to this weapon, killing them off while leaving everyone else they see as worthy unscathed.

All populations are genetically diverse, and racial categories are based on subjective evaluations of traits. All humans share the same genes, which exist in a variety of alternative forms called alleles. Since the relationship between ancestry, genetic makeup, and phenotype are so complex, there is no specific gene that can be used to determine a person's race. This makes it difficult for this group to limit the effects of this virus to one group in particular without killing anyone outside of it. How can these  terrorists develop this weapon in a way that it would exclusively target one group of people only? Would this be possible with advanced tech?

Comment: It is not possible with complete accuracy. It is possible with less then perfect accuracy. You need to establish (1) how many people are in the target subpopulation, and what this target population is (so that the respondents can look up the genetic characteristics); (2) what proportion of them can escape; (3) how many people in the general (= non-target) population can be killed. Inserting these parameters would make the question answereable.

Comment: Hello Incognito.  As luck would have it, we're in need of closing this sandbox and [opening a new one](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7183). This is occasionally necessary as the web pages get too big. If you feel this Q needs more work, may I recommend that you delete this post per the above instructions and re-post on the new site? If not, please graduate it per the instructions. Thanks!

Comment: @JBH I will delete it.