# What's a good question about world building?

Tags: discussion, on-topic

There's this site, where you ask questions about worldbuilding, so I was wondering what good question about world building are there?

Comment: Hello doctor mike, This is a much more curated forum than most. Your question belongs on the meta-side of this board. (aka where questions about how the board functions are discussed). You ought to take the tour and look around. If you require inspiration for questions read what kind of things people are asking.

Comment: Not only that, but this very question has been answered in the [help center.](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) Do not forget to [take the tour!](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/tour)

Comment: Perhaps one way to find out is to [sort existing questions by the number of votes](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=votes), presumably, the votes can be used as a metric to gauge whether a question is considered "good" by the worldbuilding community.

Answer (score 5):

Welcome to WorldBuilding *Doctor Mike*!

There are lots of different questions you could ask about WorldBuilding. It depends on what you are trying to do. The [help center](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help) gives a lot of useful information in the category [What topics can I ask about here?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic):

> For example, Worldbuilding SE welcomes questions on the following:
>
> - Creation of elements of a world (languages, species, buildings, etc.)
> - Effects of events or world elements, including biology, technology and magic, on specific aspects of that world's societies, cultures, and environment
> - How to achieve a specified effect in a defined world, including by the use of biology, technology or magic, while maintaining in-universe consistency

But you have to be careful about not asking one of the following:

> - Actions of individual characters, rather than elements of the world they inhabit
> - Character building
> - Elements of plot
> - Historical events of or historical facts about the real world, except when provided as examples or comparisons in the construction of an imaginary world (consider the History or respective subject-specific Stack Exchange sites)
> - General writing or storytelling (consider the Writing or Role-playing Games Stack Exchange sites)
> - Software that doesn't directly relate to worldbuilding (consider the Super User or Software Recommendations Stack Exchange sites)

Once you have 5 reputation and can participate here on the meta site of WorldBuilding, where we discuss for example what's on-topic or off-topic as a community, you can check out the [Sandbox](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6168/sandbox-for-proposed-questions) when you have a draft for a question to get some feedback on whether it would be on-topic or off-topic.

To earn some reputation you can check out [What is reputation? How do I earn (and lose) it?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) in the help center. You could for example suggest useful edits to other peoples posts to fix typos, or you could answer questions. Getting upvotes on questions you've asked also gives reputation. The more reputation you have, the more privileges you get - and privileges allow you to participate more on the site, especially in regards to community moderation like editing without needing approval or participating in the voting processes to temporarily put questions on hold or reopen them.

---

Basically whenever you are building a fictional world, be it for a novel, videogame, RPG or whatever else you are doing, and you encounter problems with internal consitency or need help to make some element believable you can ask here to get some help with the specific problem.

To get ideas about what's on-topic on the site you can check out for example the [monthly highest voted questions](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/?tab=month) or simply browse [all questions sorted by votes](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=votes). A little warning though: not everything that has been on-topic before is on-topic now. You should always check the help center and see what people are discussing in the comments under new questions if you want to get an idea about what's on-topic or off-topic.

If you'd like a more open-ended approach and simply brainstorm a bit, which would be off-topic on the main site, you can check out [the chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/17213/the-factory-floor) once you have 20 reputation.

Have fun on the site!

Comment: Reading the help and the tour the best thing anyone can do on a new to them SE site ;)