# Are questions about real-world religions allowed on this site?

Tags: discussion

I'm wondering, would it be okay for me to ask about real-world religion on this site? I'm not asking about how it was made, but rather its functions in the real world. I can see that this might depend a little on the question itself, so I'll show my question.

> In my story, there is murdering thief, who is quite religious. So, I want to know if there is a religion out there that focuses a lot more on question about the creation of the world and who created it, rather than moral questions and such. I need to know about a religion like this, so I can still have my character be a person of faith but still murder and thieve. Also, this religion must be a little old, and belonging to a culture. AKA, no meatball or Star Wars "force" religions.

So, would a question like this be acceptable? I read through the HELP section, and it said that question regarding real-world history is not allowed, but it didn't elaborate more on questions about the real world. If it did, I terribly misunderstood.

Comment: Hi A. Kvåle. We have a question sandbox *just* for this purpose. Feel free to use it!

Comment: Welcome to the site.  Check out the religion tag on main, may give you some ideas.  https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/religion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take the focus away from the character and move it to the world and the culture or it'll get closed as being story based.

There are religions that will answer your question with historical context and examples, but you'll have to word it carefully.

Comment: Okay, thank you. So would a question like this be acceptable: "Is there a religion out there that focuses more on the creation of the world and the creator, rather than moral grounds, commandments, etc? Preferably a religion that is a little old, and belonging to a country/ethnicity/culture?"

Comment: @A.Kvåle You're better off running this through the [sandbox](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6168/sandbox-for-proposed-questions), it's going to take a while to work out something that's not either comparative religion, history or story

Comment: Okay, good idea. Will negative reception of my question in sandbox affect my reputation? Not that I'm very concerned with reputation, but I'd like to know.

Comment: @A.Kvåle no rep changes in meta

Comment: Aha, thank you. So the option for upvote and downvote are here simply to let people know if they answer/question was good or bad?