# Big wide questions

Tags: discussion

I have some big personal opinion questions I want to discuss, that would fit perfectly into this site if they weren't so open ended.

So does anybody know where I can ask them?

Comment: *Quora*, *Yahoo! Answers* and 4Chan's */r/* are all sites that accept open ended questions or opinion-based questions.

Answer (score 6):

One possibility is to visit the [Factory Floor](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/17213/the-factory-floor), our main chat room. Depending on your timezone the activity there will vary, but in the chat we welcome open-ended opinion-based discussions about worldbuilding. This is also the perfect place for a bit of brainstorming if you are thinking about an idea, but don't have a draft yet.

If you have a draft you could also try the [Sandbox](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6168/sandbox-for-proposed-questions) where others help you to fine-tune it to the main site. If the question really is open-ended and opinion-based that won't help, but in case you are ever not sure if there isn't a way to make something on-topic it's worth it to drop a draft into the Sandbox.

If the chat is not useful to you and the question just isn't a good fit for the site then you have to try different sites. There are many good questions that just don't really fit the StackExchange Q&A style. Personally I don't use other worldbuilding related forums, but I've heard that there is a subreddit that might be helpful for you.

Comment: i hadn't thought of reddit thanks, I want to ask "what if" questions, where there really isn't a right answer,

Comment: @WendyG Few questions on Worldbuilding have an objectively "correct" answer. We do however require questions to be sufficiently constrained that we can tell whether a given answer provides an answer to the question as asked, and ideally also judge answers based on *how well* they answer the question as asked. While open-ended discussion can be interesting, it tends to fare very poorly in the Stack Exchange *Q&A format* specifically. (There's still [chat].) We've had a fair amount of discussion on "what if" questions previously; try [this Worldbuilding Meta search](/search?q=%22what+if%22).