# Can we Sandbox meta questions?

Tags: discussion, questions, sandbox, meta

Recently I saw [this question draft](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6168/sandbox-for-proposed-questions#6477) in the Sandbox, entitled "Meta Question: Should the science-based and/or hard-science tags automatically require answers to use S.I. Units?" While I look forward to seeing the discussion it will spark, I wanted to ask: Is there any precedence or specific rule relating to posting Meta question drafts in the Sandbox for proposed questions?

---

Note: Instead of asking about potential risk of being closed (which doesn't happen often in meta, as noted by @ArtificialSoul) the question instead asked about how to fix its tone to be neutral, so I would imagine that Sandboxed meta questions would have a slightly different goal in being Sandboxed.)

Comment: It is not what the Sandbox is intended for, but I don't see why not. But I don't really see a need for that. Questions on Meta don't usually get closed. Especially since there is more room for opinion on Meta than on Main.

Comment: @ArtificialSoul Good point. I updated my question to indicate that the purpose of Sandboxing the question was different from what it is usually used for. If you feel that it's okay, would you like to write an answer so as to get community feedback/voting?

Comment: @ArtificialSoul Um "This "Sandbox" is a place where Worldbuilding.SE users can get feedback on prospective questions they wish to post." it's a question, I want to post the question but I recognise I need feedback to write the question well, how then is the Sandbox not intended for this use?

Comment: @Ash I didn't mean it is not intended to sandbox questions, i just pointed out that however first introduced the idea of the sandbox did probably not consider the possibility of sandboxing meta questions. That doesn't mean it is abuse. (Like using a pencil to fix audio cassettes. Not intended for the use, but it works just fine.)

Answer (score 5):

#### No, there is no precedence (apart from the linked draft) - but why not?

The intention is to have a question Sandbox for questions on Main. For example I remember that there were arguments against it being used for questions+self-answer, but it was used like that [once](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6457/28789) (10k link) after a little [meta discussion](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6448/28789).

Personally I don't see a lot of harm in using the *Sandbox for Proposed Questions* for question drafts that go to main and question drafts that go to meta.

Especially because the traffic on meta is so slow and meta is *much, much* more lenient about on-topicness I suspect there will likely not be a whole lot of cases where people will *want* to use the Sandbox for drafting their meta question/discussion. But if you feel that you could use some help with grammar or collecting a few previous discussions about a topic or something like that the Sandbox is probably a good place. Just be explicit about it being a question intended for meta, link to meta-tags like `[meta-tag:discussion]` and add a Sandbox note about *what exactly* you expect from drafting it in the Sandbox instead of simply posting it directly. Also, you may need to expect less feedback. The main goal of the Sandbox is to help new users that have problems with main site questions. Meta discussions are really not such a big problem as far as I can tell, so people trying to help others in the Sandbox may very well focus their attention on other drafts if there is more to do.

Comment: ^ What he said!

Comment: Huh I was sure I saw a meta draft in the 2017-2018 Sandbox while we were using it.

Comment: @Ash No, there was no draft for a meta question in that Sandbox. I've read every draft that was posted there and I just looked through all of them again to make sure. I might have overlooked one or there might be one in the first Sandbox somewhere, I've only been active in the Sandbox since the end of the first Sandbox, but for all I know you are the first one to draft a discussion instead of a question in the Sandbox.

Comment: @Secespitus Cool, we'll see how it goes. You've been in the Sandbox every time I've used it so if you say it didn't happen it didn't, not in my time anyway.