# Community Promotion Ads — 2019

Tags: discussion, community-ads

2019 is here! And with the new year, as usual, comes a new iteration of **Community Promotion Ads**! Let’s refresh these for the coming year :)

#### What are Community Promotion Ads?

Community Promotion Ads are community-vetted advertisements that will show up on the main site, in the right sidebar. The purpose of this question is the vetting process. Images of the advertisements are provided, and community voting will enable the advertisements to be shown.

#### Why do we have Community Promotion Ads?

This is a method for the community to control what gets promoted to visitors on the site. For example, you might promote the following things:

- the site's amazing blog
- useful tools or resources for understanding worlds
- blogs or articles of existing interesting worlds
- cool events or conferences
- anything else your community would genuinely be interested in

The goal is for future visitors to find out about *the stuff your community deems important*. This also serves as a way to promote information and resources that are *relevant to your own community's interests*, both for those already in the community and those yet to join.

#### Why do we reset the ads every year?

Some services will maintain usefulness over the years, while other things will wane to allow for new faces to show up. Resetting the ads every year helps accommodate this, and allows old ads that have served their purpose to be cycled out for fresher ads for newer things. This helps keep the material in the ads relevant to not just the subject matter of the community, but to the current status of the community. We reset the ads once a year, every December.

The community promotion ads have no restrictions against reposting an ad from a previous cycle. If a particular service or ad is very valuable to the community and will continue to be so, it is a good idea to repost it. It may be helpful to give it a new face in the process, so as to prevent the imagery of the ad from getting stale after a year of exposure.

#### How does it work?

The answers you post to this question *must* conform to the following rules, or they will be ignored.

1. All answers should be in the exact form of:

   ```
   [![Tagline to show on mouseover][1]][2]

      [1]: http://image-url
      [2]: http://clickthrough-url
   ```

   Please **do not add anything else to the body of the post**. If you want to discuss something, do it in the comments.
2. The question must always be tagged with the magic [community-ads](/questions/tagged/community-ads) tag. In addition to enabling the functionality of the advertisements, this tag also pre-fills the answer form with the above required form.

#### Image requirements

- The image that you create must be 300 x 250 pixels, or double that if high DPI.
- Must be hosted through our standard image uploader (imgur)
- Must be GIF or PNG
- No animated GIFs
- Absolute limit on file size of 150 KB
- If the background of the image is white or partially white, there must be a 1px border (2px if high DPI) surrounding it.

#### Score Threshold

There is a **minimum score threshold** an answer must meet (currently **6**) before it will be shown on the main site.

You can check out the ads that have met the threshold with basic click stats [here](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/ads/display/7063).

Comment: Traditionally, we would post a sample ad with the site's twitter, but unfortunately Worldbuilding does not have a twitter account. [Here's an example of one, though](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4131/community-promotion-ads-2018/4132#4132).

Comment: I have an Idea for telling people about this 'question' specifically. But I don't have the means to make it actually look good. Can anyone take my idea and make something legitamate out of it? here's a link to what I have: https://docs.google.com/document/d/11x_jXPYpGmXcGclq7KRERemkhmcEuvjy5sF1-uvoluA/edit

Comment: Would you consider leaving your idea in another format, @Elias? Personally, I wouldn't open a random GDoc, and I'd think a lot of people wouldn't either — a new Meta post could be a better idea...

Comment: no prob, I'll see what I can do

Answer (score 16):

[image: Writing.SE]

Answer (score 10):

[image: Astronomy Stack Exchange]

Comment: . . . For those who want to duck out of their created universes to learn a bit about their own. Image credit: [Sir Cumference](https://astronomy.meta.stackexchange.com/a/335/2153). We do get a lot of astronomy questions here, and people might find it to be a useful resource.

Answer (score 10):

[image: Visit Universe Factory, our community-run blog!]

Comment: In what way is the Universe Factory blog related to this board? It is published by a third party, [A Medium Corporation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Medium_(website)), and any attempt to access it is met with a scary warning: *"To make Medium work, we log user data and share it with processors; to use Medium, you must agree to our Privacy Policy, including cookie policy"*. To post a comment requires signing in to the A Medium Corporation and giving them access to personal data, including *"information associated with that third-party account, such as your lists of friends or followers"*.

Comment: @AlexP Medium is the *platform*, but the blog content is by, and managed by, members of the Worldbuilding community.  Medium logs your data in roughly the same way that Twitter or WordPress (hosted) or Tumblr does.  (Handwave because I haven't read all those sites' privacy policies in detail.)  Medium was recommended to us by SE.  (By the way, you'll see similar warnings if you access SE while not logged in.)

Comment: All right, I understand. I still believe that, with no Creative Commons notice to be seen, a more honest description would have been "a column in Medium, a for-profit publication of the A Medium Corporation corporation"; but I understand the intention and the spirit of the advertisement.

Comment: Blog posts, unlike content here on SE, are not licensed under Creative Commons.  The authors (not Medium) own the copyright.  Some authors might also license their posts under CC, but if you want to use something and you're not sure, ask the author.  (Comments are enabled on the blog.)

Answer (score 10):

[image: Q&A about science fiction and fantasy]

Comment: Copied from [2017](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4432/2235); ad designed by CreationEdge.

Answer (score 9):

[image: Share your work on the blog. We'll help!]

Comment: **PS:** Thanks to @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 for providing the source image

Answer (score 9):

[image: The best questions are perfected first in our Sandbox!]

Answer (score 9):

[image: Help in the Sandbox as a Mentor!]

Answer (score 5):

[image: Be inspired by stories]

Comment: Copied from [2017](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4382/2235); ad mostly designed by BESW.

Comment: Personally, I actually prefer the [Lit ad on SFF](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/12299/32756); I find the font and size easier to read.  FWIW.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Comment: Background image is [in the public domain](https://phys.org/news/2018-05-theoretical-analysis-sand-mega-ripples.html).

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Comment: This is a general-purpose ad that can be redirected to whichever swag offer is active (if any) at the time.  Currently it redirects [here](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7313/40609).

Answer (score -1):

[image]

Comment: I have mixed feelings about this ad. It has the potential to make people feel bad if they haven't accepted answers, but that could simply be because none of the answers they've gotten recently is good enough to be accepted (it happens). So I think it sends the wrong message by implying that they're not a good user if they don't accept answers.

Comment: @HDE226868 I've occasionally wandered through the historical records and wondered if half or more of the problem was that they simply forgot.  But, jompi-kumpi.