# Worldbuilding Custom Journals - Want one?

Tags: discussion

### Journals are in my posession!  If you ordered one [click here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/99879/world-building-journals) so we can sort out shipping.

---

I have been working with Stack and a vendor to try and sort out getting [custom Moleskine journals](https://www.jennibick.com/products/classic-hardcover-moleskine-notebook-sapphire-blue) created for Worldbuilding.

After...eh...a bit of time, think we are ready to go.

**The planned swag:**

- Blue hard cover moleskine notebook
- Worldbuilding stamped into the front cover
- A full page color insert inside the front cover featuring Slarti and Pandora from the main site art (similar to the full-color image [in this design update](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3353/28))
- 8.5" x 5" (216 x 127mm)
- Blank (unlined) pages

**Cost:**

- Approximately 25-26 USD (including shipping in the US)
- Cost will be higher for non-US users, based on shipping costs.  Best guess is 20-25 USD in shipping costs at this time.  We welcome suggestions for ways to lower shipping costs -- if you've tackled this problem in the past and have ideas, please comment.

**Distribution:**

- At this point in time, I will likely order them have them delivered to me and then distributed.  I do have a question out to SE.  If they are up for it I will have them distribute.  **This means you will need to be willing to share your mailing address with me and to pay online via Venmo/Paypal or something else.**

If you are going to purchase one of the journals please add your name so I can get a count.

**DO NOT ADD YOUR NAME TO THE LIST IF YOU ARE JUST INTERESTED, I NEED TO KNOW YOU WILL BE BUYING**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hey there world builders.  If you didn't get in on the initial order and would like a journal you can order them individually now that the initial setup stuff has been taken care of.

They are exceptionally awesome by the way. Worldbuilding (in the site font) is stamped into the front cover and the poster from the site design (below) is printed full color inside the front cover.  We ordered them in sapphire blue but I'd hazard a guess you can get them in any color you want.

**If you want one check out:**  https://www.jennibick.com/

**Reference order #LG-8699** <- this has all the info the binder needs to get the right set up for you.

Answer (score 3):

### Journal received!!

And it looks **amazing**. Can’t wait to fill it with half-built worlds :)

[image: Cover photo]

[image]

Thanks again @James for making this happen!